# Non-compactness of $(1,3)$ and $[x,\infty)$ only using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Working from the definition of compactness, determine which of the following subsets of R are compact and prove your assertion.

1. $(1,3)$
2. $[x,\infty)$ where $x$ is finite

I know that both of these are not compact. I know that I need to show that there is a open cover that does not contain a finite sub cover. For 1, The problem is at the points 1 and 3. and for 2 the problem is at infinity. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: **Hint:** Try to make some drawings of open covers. You'll probably understand what you have to use to show that these sets are not compact.

Comment: Consider the sequence of intervals $(1, 3-\frac{1}{n})$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. What can you say about this sequence?

Comment: That the sequence will not cover the entire interval, or if you take a finite many of n's that it will no longer cover the entire set?

Comment: what if i had [1,3] how would I show that that IS compact?

Answer (score 1):

$\bigcup_n (1+\frac{1}{n},3)$ for $(1,3)$ is an open cover with no finite subcover. Similarly $\bigcup_n(x-\frac{1}{n}, n)$ for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

For $[x,+\infty)$ set $U_n = [x,x+n)$ for integer $n \ge 1$.

The $U_n$ is an open cover of $[x,+\infty)$ having no finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

1.... $\{(x,3): x>1\}.$

2.... $\{(u,v):u,v\in \Bbb R\}.$